# How to perform double click on a word within an div element which has long text strings using nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, dom, testing, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

i am testing a web application, i want to perform double click on a word within multiple text strings under an element, for the reference i am attaching an image.[image]

as you can see a highlighted text in a div element, i want to do double click on this word using nightwatch.js.

i tried in following way but it is selecting random word from element text, e.g. sometime selecting ***"the"*** sometime *"**grass**"* and sometime *"**eat**"* from this div element.

```
client.moveTo('.pf3 div div:nth-child(5)').doubleClick();
```

I can get my desired word "***and***" from dummy string using javaScript like following.

```
var str = 'I went up to Scotland with my dad and';
var ohh = str.substring(34, 37);
console.log(ohh);
```

so i will get my desired word ***"and"*** from the above string, but how i will do double click on it? because if i will perform double click on element than it will select entire string not my desired word.